# Doctrine ODM (MongoDB) MapReduce + Skip

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, doctrine-odm

I'm working on with a set where I need to use batch-querying due to Doctrine's - and Mongo's - `reduce` output limitations. However, I'm stupefied about how to do so.

Doctrine ODM's `MapReduce` doesn't allow the `Skip` option. However, I've found and read about injecting a variable into `Scope` (let's say `n`), where it can act as a global counter for the `MapReduce`, and with an `if()` check it can effectively skip emits where the counter is less than `n`.

However, those explanations were for MongoDB's JS implementations (mongoose etc.), whereas I'm working with Doctrine ODM, so I've no idea how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging through the `QueryBuilder` class, I've found `mapReduceOptions(array)` so added the following to my query after the `map`:

```
->mapReduceOptions(array('scope'=>array('skip'=>$BatchSkip,'counter'=>0)))`
```

i.e.

```
->map($map)
->mapReduceOptions(array('scope'=>array('skip'=>$BatchSkip,'counter'=>0)))
->reduce($reduce)
->getQuery()->execute()
```

I then wrapped everything in my `map` function with `if (counter >= skip && counter < (skip+100))`

```
$map = "function(){
  if (counter >= skip && counter < (skip+100))
  { 
    .
    .
    .
    emit( key, value ); 
  }";
```

and I increment `$BatchSkip` in my PHP batch loop.

```
$BatchSkip+=100;
```

That does the trick.
Reference: MongoDB mapReduce options:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce